# Google Drive SDK permissions delete not taking effect

Tags: google-drive-api

- I created a document in Google Docs and noted the unique file ID in the URL
- I visited https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list and used the "Try it!" API Explorer at the bottom of the page to confirm that I am listed as the sole user with "owner" permissions
- I visited https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert and added permissions in for a new user with values `{"role":"writer", "type":"user", "value":"someone@example.com"}`
- I returned to https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list and verified that the new user has been granted permissions
- I visited https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/delete and "removed" the user's permission using the file ID and their permission ID (with a 204 response)
- I returned to https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list and found, to my disappointment, that the user still had access

Am I missing something here or is the API broken in this regard?

Comment: drive broke last week. it is currently unknown when it might be fixed. you are probably experiencing that bug

Comment: Wouldn't happen to have a citation for this, would you? Googling "google drive sdk status" gets me nowhere.

Comment: This is the best I've got . https://plus.google.com/106160348960403302854/posts/Q7EXHjHiSC5 If you scroll back through [google-drive-sdk] questions for last week, you'll see a bunch of similar questions were being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per pinoyyid's comment, this was an ephemeral error in Google's Drive SDK that has since been resolved.